# branch 間の関係を、適度に単純化して出力することはできますか

Tags: git

branch 達の関係を見たいときに、たとえば`git log --graph branch1 branch2 ...` として出力すると、それらの branch から辿れる全ての歴史が出力されてしまいます。

欲しいのは、もう少し、適度に単純化された、branch 間の関係を知るのに必要な分だけのコミットからなるコミットグラフなのですが、それを計算・出力する方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--simplify-by-decoration` というオプションがありますが、これでどうでしょうか。

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --branches --simplify-by-decoration
```

Answer (score 3):

[Git-のさまざまなツール-リビジョンの選択](http://git-scm.com/book/ja/v1/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%96%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E) によりますと、以下の様な指定方法で多少なりとも単純化されます。

**ダブルドット**

例:

```
$ git log --graph master..experiment
```

意味:

> experiment からはたどれるけれど、master からはたどれないすべてのコミット

**トリプルドット**

例:

```
$ git log --graph master...experiment
```

意味:

> ふたつの参照のうちどちらか一方からのみたどれるコミット